# Не могу получить все cookie

Tags: php, curl, cookie

Использую CURL для получения данных с сайта. Если просматривать эту ссылку в браузере - там есть много cookie. Если кликнув по ссылке выбрать Copy as cURL - все  переменные cookie там будут.

Но если я хочу сохранить cookie с помощью php функции curl - то там нету всех cookie. Почему так? Надо указывать какой то дополнительный параметр?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет добавление заголовка User-Agent?

Comment: Вы уверены что куки принадлежат именно именно этому домену? Есть куки, например, от Яндекс метрики... их не будет. А также куки, которые создаются с помощью js....